# Version `GFORTRAN_1.4` not found OPENBLAS

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to install OPENBLAS from git. I've cloned the directory and when I run `make NO_AFFINITY=1 USE_OPENMP=1` I get this error

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sandesh/OpenBLAS/test'
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o sblat1 sblat1.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o dblat1 dblat1.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o cblat1 cblat1.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o zblat1 zblat1.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o sblat2 sblat2.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o dblat2 dblat2.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o cblat2 cblat2.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o zblat2 zblat2.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o sblat3 sblat3.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o dblat3 dblat3.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o cblat3 cblat3.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
gfortran -Wall -m64   -o zblat3 zblat3.o ../libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.16.dev.a -lm -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lpthread -lgfortran 
OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./sblat1
./sblat1: /home/sandesh/anaconda/lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by ./sblat1)
make[1]: *** [level1] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

My gcc compiler is `gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)` and I believe fortran is already 1.4 in gcc 4.8.1

I feel the problem is that the compiler is using the gcc from the folder anaconda which I had installed last week.
How should I point the make command to use my default gcc compiler ?

Answer (score 1):

Guys I found a work around here by using this command .... 
Seems like the libfortran from the anaconda folder was causing issue so I tried to use my default libfortran which happened to be of correct version ...
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 make NO_AFFINITY=1 USE_OPENMP=1`
Reference: [answer by flying sheep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628273/libgfortran-version-gfortran-1-4-not-found)